# Python 2.7 Join two values as list in same row of two different columns (from csv file)

Tags: python-2.7, list, csv, row, col

I have a .csv file with two columns of interest 'latitude' and 'longitude' with populated values

I would like to return [latitude, longitude] pairs of each row from the two columns as lists...

[10.222, 20.445]
[10.2555, 20.119] ... and so forth for each row of my csv...

The problem with
>
    import pandas
    colnames = [ 'latitude', 'longitude']
    data = pandas.read_csv('path_name.csv', names=colnames)

```
latitude = data.latitude.tolist()
longitude = data.longitude.tolist()
```

is that it creates two lists for all the values each latitude and longitude column

How can I create lists for each latitude, longitude pair in python ?

Answer (score 1):

Most basic way

```
import csv
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as csvfile:
     spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
     for row in spamreader:
         print row
```

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for, it still returns two lists, one of all values in latitude and another of all values in longitude...

Answer (score 0):

So from what I understand is that you want many lists of two elements: lat and long.  However what you are receiving is two lists, one of lat and one of long.  what I would do is loop over the length of those lists and then take that element in the lat/long lists and put them together in their own list.

```
for x in range(0, len(latitude)):
    newList = [latitude[x], longitude[x]]
```

Comment: Yes, the idea is to create list pairs based on same indexes.

Comment: Did this help you at all?